# ORA-06550 store procedure error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle11g

I have a store procedure like this

```
PROCEDURE PRC_ABCD_GETALL (resultset_out OUT TYPES.cursorType)
AS
BEGIN
OPEN 
resultset_out FOR SELECT * FROM ABCD;
END PRC_ABCD_GETALL;
```

and this procedure is in package and the package is like this

```
create or replace
PACKAGE        V4_EVT_PKG_ABCD_GENERAL
AS
PROCEDURE PRC_ABCD_GETALL (resultset_out OUT TYPES.cursorType);
END V4_EVT_PKG_ABCD_GENERAL;
```

and the oracle data provider was system.data.oracleClient and the previous  code is this

```
public static IEnumerable<PortalList> GetAll()
{
  Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
  DbCommand objComm = db.GetStoredProcCommand("package_name.sp", new 
  object[1]);          
  var result = new List<PortalList>();         
  using (IDataReader rdr = db.ExecuteReader(objComm))
  {            
    while (rdr.Read())
    {                   
      result.Add(Construct(rdr));               
    }           
  }         
return result;
```

}

and now I found out that system.data.oracleClient is depricated and i want to use Oracle.DataAccess.Client as data provider I wrote C# code for this but I am facing some errors like wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRC_ABCD_GETALL' in this function PortalListRepository.GetAll();

```
private static IEnumerable<PortalList> GetAll(bool forceDataReload)
{
    const string cacheKey = "PortalListService_GetAll";
    IEnumerable<PortalList> result = null;
    if (!forceDataReload)
        result = GetFromCache(cacheKey);
    if (result == null)
    {
        result = PortalListRepository.GetAll();
        AddToCache(cacheKey, result);
    }

    return result;
 }
```

that I can't solve.

C# code

```
public static IEnumerable<PortalList> GetAll()
{
  string cnn = "connectionstring";
  var result = new List<PortalList>();
  using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnn))
  {
        conn.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "PRC_ABCD_GETALL";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("resultset_out", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();              
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            result.Add(Construct(rdr));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am very much new to this I don't know how to solve it.Anybody have any idea what am i doing wrong in C# code or in my store procedure or in my package??pls help I have been trying this almost 3 weeks but no luck :(((

Comment: Your code and error don't match. Is this the real code?

Comment: yes i wrote this code. the problem is if i close this  cmd.Parameters.Add("resultset_out", OracleType.Cursor, 
  ParameterDirection.Output); then i get                                            
 "ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PRC_ABCD_GETALL'\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored". Can you help me on this I searched everything but no luck :( .

Comment: Can you execute your stored procedure from sql developer correctly? Is there a reason you're using a cursor?

Comment: hi thanks for reply :) . this is all done by previous developer.every store procedure in my project has same resultset_out OUT TYPES.cursorType.  i'm trying to correct it but i am confused with TYPES.cursortype . i never worked with this .can you tell me what to correct in package or in store procedure or in C# code.i will attach screenshots of my procedure execution into sql developer for more details.your reply is really valuable for me.i'm trying to solve this more than 3 weeks but no luck at all :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved this error after banging my heads against wall for weeks after weeks ohhhh god.Why I was having this error is that I installed 32 bit oracle 12c into my 64 bit os that's why it can't load assemblies of oracle.data.accesss dll's and it throws these exception.

Sollution:
Go to your project->property->built->any cpu or 64bit I did any cpu it solved my problem.

For further details go to this link:

https://rambletech.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-oracle-dataaccess-error/